# Can I execute npm commands directly from the visual studio

Tags: c#, npm, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Can I execute npm commands (e.g. npm init, npm install) directly from Visual Studio 2017 on Asp.Net Core 2.0 project? May be from command line or context menu?
Now I have context menu command for Bower, when right click on MVC project in Solution Explorer, but i'm not use bower in my project.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the Package Manager Console like you would a regular console. The Package Manager Console in Visual Studio acts like a PowerShell console. NPM commands such as `init` and `install` are available if `npm` is on your classpath.

The Package Manager Console is found under Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution if you want separate window instead of Package Manager Console: [NPM task runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner)

This tool will add fancy window to run commands from `package.json` file (I assume you have one)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new tool included in Visual Studio v15.8 called [Library Manager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/31/library-manager-release-in-15-8/) for installing client side libraries. I've been trying it out after looking for a quick and easy solution to install NPM packages, and I must say it has been a pleasure to use!

You can install any NPM package by simply selecting the `UnPkg` provider in the GUI, or setting it in your libman.json file, like so:

```
"defaultProvider": "UnPkg"
```

Fast, lightweight, and works like a charm. Give it a try!